# Column that sums values once per unique ID, while filtering on type (Oracle Fusion Transportation Intelligence)

Tags: oracle

I realize that this has been discussed before but haven't seen a solution in a simple CASE expression for adding a column in Oracle FTI - which is as far as my experience goes at the moment unfortunately. My end goal is to have an total Weight for each Category only counting the null type entries and only one Weight per ID (Don't know why null was chosen as the default Type). I need to break the data apart by Type for a total Cost column which is working fine so I didn't include that in the example data below, but because I have to break the data up by Type, I am having trouble eliminating redundant values in my Total Weight results.

My original column which included redundant weights was as follows:

```
SUM(CASE Type
WHEN null
THEN 'Weight'
ELSE null 
END)
```

Some additional info:

- Each ID can have multiple Types  (additionally each ID may not always have A or B but should always have null)
- Each ID can only have one Weight (But when broken apart by type the value just repeats and messes up results)
- Each ID can only have one Category (This doesn't really matter since I already separate this out with a Category column in the results)

**Example Data:**

`ID |Categ. |Type   | Weight
 1  | Old   | A     | 1600
 1  | Old   | B     | 1600
 1  | Old   |(null) | 1600
 2  | Old   | B     | 400
 2  | Old   |(null) | 400
 2  | Old   |(null) | 400
 3  | New   | A     | 500
 3  | New   | B     | 500
 3  | New   |(null) | 500
 4  | New   | A     | 500
 4  | New   |(null) | 500
 4  | New   |(null) | 500`

**Desired Results:**

`Categ.  | Total Weight
Old     | 2000
New     | 1000`

I was trying to figure out how to include a DISTINCT based on ID in the column, but when I put DISTINCT in front of CASE it just eliminates redundant weights so I would just get 500 for Total Weight New.

Additionally, I thought it would be possible to divide the weight by the count of weights before aggregating them, but this didn't seem to work either:

```
SUM(CASE Type
WHEN null
THEN 'Weight'/COUNT(CASE Type
                    WHEN null
                    THEN 'Weight'
                    ELSE null
                    END)
ELSE null 
END)
```

I am very appreciative of any help that can be offered, please let me know if there is a simple way to create a column that achieves the desired results.  As it may be apparent, I am pretty new to Oracle, so please let me know if there is any additional information that is needed.

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a case statement here. You were on the right track with `distinct`, but you also need to use an `inline view` (a subquery in the from the caluse).

The subquery in the from clause, selecting all distinct combinations of (id, categ, weight), allows you to then select from the result set, whereby you select only categ, sum of weight, grouping by categ. The subquery in the from clause has no repeated weights for a given id (unlike the table itself, which is why this is needed).

This would have to be done a little differently if an id were ever to have more than one category, but you noted that an id only ever has one category.

```
select categ,
       sum(weight)
  from (select distinct id,
                        categ,
                        weight
          from tbl)
 group by categ;
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11a56/1/0

Comment: Hi Brian - Thanks for the suggestions.

I tried to copy this into a column in Oracle FTI and put what I thought was the correct table name in place of "tbl" but was not able to save the column - getting the error : 
'Invalid Alias Format : Table_name.Column_name required.'

Is this type of query possible in a column in Oracle FTI?

Comment: @wcs531 what do you mean by "save the column"?

Comment: Sorry if I did not make it clear in the original question.  I am creating an Adhoc report in Fusion Transportation Intelligence and I am trying to save this query as a custom column in a search that will also include columns for total cost etc. (I was ignoring the other columns in this question for the sake of simplicity) 

So I am going to Edit Column Formula and entering the query there.

Comment: The above is a whole query, not a column. You can't put this as an item in a select list, it's a query from start to finish. In that tool do you have the ability to query an inline view (a subquery in the from clause)? If not are you able to use subqueries at all? You could alternatively use subqueries in the where clause to get the same result, if the tool allows for that. If you have access to the database itself, you would just run the above.

Comment: Hi Brian - I appreciate your help so far.  I have been running the query in the advanced tab where it lets you paste in your own queries as opposed to Oracle building it.

I was able to run the basic query:
'select categ,
       sum(weight)
          from tbl'
and the query within the parenthesis:
'select distinct id,
                        categ,
                        weight
          from tbl'
For some reason I am having trouble running the inline query where the subquery is supposed to be the table for the main query.  I will continue to play around with it as I have time and update here